# Laravel: sending to views messages with special characters

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working with Laravel 5 and trying to pass some custom messages to my views using Redirect::route() with parameters, but if the message has special characters ('ñ', 'ó', etc), it never reaches the view. The same happens with validator custom messages.

For example, this code doesn't work (because of the 'ñ'):

```
return Redirect::route('account-modificar')
                ->with('global', 'Error: Contraseña incorrecta.');
```

If I remove that character, the same code works:

```
return Redirect::route('account-modificar')
                ->with('global', 'Error: Contrasena incorrecta.');
```

Is there any way to make the first code work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are your files UTF-8 encoded? Do you get any errors?

Comment: If by files you refer to my views, yes, they are UTF-8 encoded. I don't get any errors, the message simply doesn't reach the view or it does not show up where it should.

Comment: Ah, fixed. I was using notepad++ to edit my files and the encoding in the editor was set to "ANSI" instead of "UTF-8 without BOM". Changing the encoding in the editor itself solved the issue. Thanks for your time anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I fixed the problem. It has nothing to do with laravel or the views, but with my editor. I was using Notepad++ and the encoding was set to ANSI, so even if I couldn't see any real difference, the file was being saved with a wrong format.

To fix this, I had to change the encoding of the file in the editor to "UTF-8 without BOM" and rewrite any special character on the document.

Hope this helps more people with the same issue.

Edit: Just realized Ravan was refering to this in his comment above, I thought he was refering to the encoding in the meta section of the view, so credit to him because he was the first to notice the problem.